# PHP : How to display image from blob

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a little problem here.
I try to convert an image into string base64, after that I want to save the string into blob in MySQL.
So, the blob can be displayed on the mobile apps.

this is my code :

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"]);
$image = base64_encode($data);
```

I already successfully save the blob into MySQL, but I can not displayed the image in website.

```
<td> <img src="<?php echo base64_decode($user->getPicture()); ?>"></td>
```

because the result is : `������� and many more`

Am I wrong ?
Please correct me :)

Comment: @u_mulder Hes not using short tags so your response shouldn't use them either otherwise it might cause undue confusion. Also he needs `data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_decode($user->getPicture()); ?>` of course the mime type need to be relevant tot he image.. ie`image/jpeg` or whatever it actually is.

Comment: The URI should look like `src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..."` - you are missing the `data:image...(etc.)` part it seems?

Comment: @prodigitalson : I already put data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_decode($user->getPicture()); ?>, but my image did not displaying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `src` attribute of an image MUST point at a url. You cannot dump the raw binary contents of an image in there and expect it to work. The browser will take that raw binary data and try to hit the page's originating server and request that data as if it was a file url. i.e. you have this on a page loaded from `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz.php`:

```
<img src="blahblahblahblah" />
```

which will result in the browser requesting

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/blahblahblahblah
```

If you want to embed your image in the page, then you have to use a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $base64_encoded_image ?>" />
```

Comment: I already put data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_decode($user->getPicture()); ?>, but my image did not displaying

Comment: yes, but you're **DECODING**, which means you're stuffing the raw binary data into the data uri.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? I feel confused here

Comment: your already base64-encoded your image to insert it into the db. so you don't have to do ANYTHING... just take the text you selected from the db and put it into the data uri. base64_decode() will return your image to raw binary garbage, which CAN'T be used in a data uri

Comment: I already try `data:image/png/base64;<?php echo $user->getPicture();?>`, but the picture still do not showing

Comment: oops, sorry. had a typo in the data uri syntax. should be `data:image/png;base64,`

Comment: thanks already solved, but the image didn't show up full, any ideas?